# Support Vector Machine algorithm for image classification

Tags: java, computer-vision

I am trying to classify images based on Support Vector Machine(SVM). But didn't get any proper algorithm for implementation. Any help in classifying images based on SVM is acceptable. i.e. How SVM works in image classification ? SVM algorithm for implementation in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean Support Vector *Machines*...

SVM is included in the [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html) for MATLAB and in the [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) library, which is in Java. And, of course, there is [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/)

As to how to use SVM for classifying images, that is a very broad question.  First you need to decide on how to represent the images as feature vectors that you can feed into the SVM.  And how to do that depends on your specific problem domain.  There are lots of research papers on the subject.

Comment: Yes It is support vector machine. I have represent images in homogeneity,correlation,contrast,energy features. Now i have to use SVM for categorize images based on skin amount available in image.

Comment: Ok, can you arrange those features into a vector?  One vector per image? If so, then you can create a training set from these vectors and the corresponding lables (e.g. "skin" or "no skin"). Then you pass the training set to the `svmtrain` function, or whatever it is called in your implementation. You would need to look at the documentation for whatever implementation you use for more details.